# Binary Search Tree Issues

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm working on a binary tree with a list tacked on to the data, yet I can't tell if the list is being populated or not. The code runs alright but when I try to call to print out the tree I get a freeze in my code. I believe everything is being pointed to properly but it's obvious there is a flaw in the logic somewhere.

struct declarations

```
typedef struct lineList
{
    int lineNum;
    LIST *next;
}LIST;

typedef struct nodeTag{
   char data[80];
   LIST *lines;
   struct nodeTag *left;
   struct nodeTag *right;
} NODE;
```

declaration and pass to function from main

```
NODE *root = NULL;
readFromFile(argv[1], root);
```

readfromfile(working function) then calls insertword

```
insertWord(root, keyword, lineNum);
```

insertWord, addToList functions(problem area)

```
NODE *allocateNode(char *data, int line)
{
    NODE *root;
    LIST *newNum;
    if(!(root = (NODE *) malloc (sizeof(NODE))))
        printf( "Fatal malloc error!\n" ), exit(1);

    strcpy(root->data, data); //copy word
    (root)->left  = (root)->right = root->lines = NULL; //initialize

    if (!(newNum =(LIST *) malloc (sizeof(LIST))))
        printf( "Fatal malloc error!\n" ), exit(1);
    newNum->lineNum = line;
    root->lines = newNum;

    return root;
}

/****************************************************************
   ITERATIVE Insert
*/
NODE *insertWord(NODE *root, char *data, int line)
{
    NODE *ptr_root = root;
    printf("inserting %s\n", data);

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = allocateNode(data, line);
        return root;
    }
    while(ptr_root)
    {   
      if (strcmp(data, ptr_root->data > 0))
      {
          if(ptr_root->right)
            ptr_root = ptr_root->right;  //traverse right
          else
            ptr_root->right = allocateNode(data, line);
      }
      else if (strcmp(data, ptr_root->data) < 0)
      { 
          if(ptr_root->left) //traverse left
            ptr_root = ptr_root->left;
          else
            ptr_root->left = allocateNode(data, line);
      }
      else
        {
            printf("Node already in the tree!\n");
            addToList(ptr_root, line);
        }
    }
    printf("5\n");
   return root;
}

void printTreeInorder(NODE *root)//simple print, freeze on call to function
{   
   if(root)
    {
      printTreeInorder(root->left);
      printf( "%s\n",  root->data );
      printTreeInorder(root->right);
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: Where is your printTree function?

Comment: @Jim added, although I freeze on call to it, it does not yet print the list of ints.

Comment: edited for new logic, even still, root is always NULL inside of `insertWord`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at `insertWord()`:

1. At the end of your while loop, we know that `ptr_root == NULL`.
2. We then allocate memory for `ptr_root`.
3. We then initialize the contents of `ptr_root`.
4. We then perform a **memory leak** on `ptr_root`.

Note that you need to retain the parent of the new node, and you need to point the its left or right pointer to this new node.

It also sounds like you understand how to use a debugger. If that's true, you should be able to see that `root` doesn't change between calls to `insertWord()`.

---

In the code that you've posted with an attempted fix, you're missing one key thing. Let's look at a function:

```
void foo(NODE *root) {
    printf("before malloc:   %p\n", root);
    root = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    printf("after malloc:    %p\n", root);
}

int main() {
    NODE *root = NULL;
    printf("before function: %p\n", root);
    foo(root);
    printf("after function:  %p\n", root);
}
```

This code will produce:

```
before function: 0x0
before malloc:   0x0
after malloc:    0x123ab129
after function:  0x0
```

Note that any changes to the value of `root` is not propagated out of the function. Things that you change to `*root` would though.

Comment: EDIT: my brain is working a bit better now after contemplating the issue. Seeing the logic now.

Comment: @lloyd: I've added some additional thoughts that might be helpful.